# I have a tab delimited data frame sorted by the first column, how can I add an empty line between unique values of the first column?

Tags: bash

I would like my data to look like:

```
-2 -2 1
-2 -1 0
-2  0 1
-2  1 1.5
-2  2 2

-1 -2 1.5
-1 -1 0.5
-1  0 1.5
-1  1 1
-1  2 1.5

0 -2 1.3
0 -1 0.2
0  0 1.6
0  1 1.2
0  2 2.3
```

Where there are 3 tab separated columns total, all 3 data types are doubles, and the first column is separated by unique values by a newline.

Currently, I have similar data, but no separation. Any ideas on how I can do this in bash or something similar?

Comment: Did you try some efforts on your own?

Comment: Yes I wrote a short script in Java, but I was hoping there would be something less verbose to incorporate in a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $1 != prev {print ""} {print; prev=$1}' file
```

Comment: Add some description on your answer to understand it.